# Keeping accurate conditions during loop repetition

Tags: c#

I'm doing one method for calculating a pause, which has certain breaks checks. The method of calculating the time (from-to), at the same time I want to check, and if the time is less than 30, let me report the error.

It would have succeeded in a commencement if the loop would not have been repeated.

Can I somehow, if the condition is correct, skip that part?

In the pause of the variables I come to my values: 6, 56, 4

this is the method

```
private double CalculateBreak(List<PRAESENZZEIT> arrivals, out string error)
{
    error = null;
    double totalBreak = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < arrivals.Count();)
    {
        for (int n=i-1; n < arrivals.Count();)
        {
            double pause = (arrivals[i].ZPZ_Von - arrivals[n].ZPZ_Bis).TotalMinutes;
            //this part
            if (pause > 30) 
                error = "OK"; 
            else
                error = "error1";
            //end
            i += 1;
            totalBreak += pause;
            break;
        }
        if (totalBreak < 60)
        {
            error = "error2";
        }
    }
    return totalBreak;
}
```

Comment: You should move the `error = "OK";` to the top of the method. if there was any error,  you shouldn't overwrite it the next iteration with OK  (`error = null;` => `error = "OK`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Edit: after some to-and-fro in the comments there is a further change required. If this still doesn't do what you want then lease open another question which concentrates on that part alone because I have no idea what you're saying. Code in the original answer commented out. This now returns the error if there has been one*

Your loops are wrong. You only need one of them. The for n loop is going through all arrivals, when it looks like you only need to look at the previous one. Try something like this:

```
private double CalculateBreak(List<PRAESENZZEIT> arrivals, out string error)
{
    error = null;
    double totalBreak = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < arrivals.Count();)
    {
        // Check the i-th against the previous one (i - 1)
        double pause = (arrivals[i].ZPZ_Von - arrivals[i - 1].ZPZ_Bis).TotalMinutes;
        // //this part
        // if (pause > 30) 
        //     error = "OK"; 
        // else
        if (pause < 30) // new
        {               // new
            error = "Pausenzeitverletzung";
        }               // new
        //end
        i += 1;
        totalBreak += pause;
        // break;
        // if (totalBreak < 60)
        // {
        //    error = "Pausenzeitverletzung";
        // }
    }
    // new: moved if block
    if (totalBreak < 60)
    {
        error = "Pausenzeitverletzung";
    }

    return totalBreak;
}
```

Comment: You were just a little earlier than I. :) It might be worth to mention to the OP, that the `arrivals` list is assumed to be sorted correctly...

Comment: That code should indeed give you 6, then 56, then 4 as you said you wanted. The totalBreak returned will be 66. That may not be what you want, but your code is adding up all breaks and ignoring that some are < 30. Your next problem may be in calculating totalBreak. (BTW: just saying 'not working' doesn't help much. What is actually happening? What should be happening? I have no idea from what you've just said.)

Comment: Also, as @BartHofland said (:) it does assume that the arrivals are sorted properly.

Comment: OK. You want to return a List (6,56,4) as well as the other two things it is returning? Well, add that code then.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the start of the function and step through it. Watch what it's doing.